# Завершение телефонного звонка, программно

Tags: java, android

У меня телефон Samsung J5 с android 6.0
подскажите, пошагово, как сбросить входящий телефонный звонок?

в manifest я указываю два разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

создаю `BroadcastReceiver`, а дальше..... куча вариантов из нета, которые у меня не работают

Comment: в manifest я указываю два разрешеня <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> и <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: создаю BroadcastReceiver

Comment: а дальше.....    куча вариантов из нета, которые у меня не работают